# Should a heading "Navigation" be above a following <nav> element, or inside it?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup

What is better:

```
<h1>Navigation</h1>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Or:

```
<nav>
  <h1>Navigation</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Is there any significant difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nav` is a sectioning element and as such, if you have a heading that describes the navigation it should be inside:

```
<nav>
  <h1>Navigation</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Otherwise, the heading will be incorrectly associated with a different section altogether, rather than the `nav` element.

The [W3C HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element) provides a near-identical example:

> **Code Example:**
>
> In the following example, the page has several places where links are present, but only one of those places is considered a navigation section.
>
> ```
> <body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
>  <header>
>   <h1>Wake up sheeple!</h1>
>   <p><a href="news.html">News</a> -
>      <a href="blog.html">Blog</a> -
>      <a href="forums.html">Forums</a></p>
>   <p>Last Modified: <span itemprop="dateModified">2009-04-01</span></p>
>   <nav>
>    <h1>Navigation</h1>
>    <ul>
>     <li><a href="articles.html">Index of all articles</a></li>
>     <li><a href="today.html">Things sheeple need to wake up for today</a></li>
>     <li><a href="successes.html">Sheeple we have managed to wake</a></li>
>    </ul>
>   </nav>
>  </header>
>  ...
> </body>
> ```

Comment: While I agree with you that this is better practice, your statement on incorrectly associated heading is not correct. Headings in HTML apply until the next heading is encountered. They are not hierarchical unless you are using hierarchical ARIA heading levels.

Comment: @unobf: They are hierarchical in HTML5. See [section 4.3.10](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#headings-and-sections) of the same spec I link to above. To be completely precise, the nav *does* outline as a subsection of the implicit section created by the heading if placed outside, but the heading does not pertain directly to the nav in that case. Whether this is merely a question of best practices depends on whether the author considers the outline to be canon (seeing as there are no known UA implementations of the outline yet, only [pet tools](https://hoyois.github.io/html5outliner)).

Answer (score 1):

If you're wondering about accessibility [take a look here.](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/59947/what-is-the-most-usable-navigation-mark-up-for-screen-readers)

It is best to use a header inside the `nav` as it is describing the section.

Answer (score 0):

Having the heading inside the `<nav>` container allows you to more easily style it, and manipulate the nav element as a whole. If you moved the `<nav>` for instance, you'd likely want the heading to go with it. It just saves work and makes thing simpler to have it inside.

You will be able to style it using:

```
nav h1 {
    style: something funky;
}
```

Instead of styling all h1 elements or giving it an ID.

Answer (score -2):

The first one is better because the heading should describe what to come, and is not a part of the nav. Just like h1 should not be inside p. It will probably work just fine either way though.

Comment: While this is true in most cases, nav is in fact a sectioning element rather than simply flow content, so the h1 should be inside it, just like an h1 should be inside a section rather than outside.